# What's the right UIControlState for the UIButton being pressed?

Tags: iphone, uibutton, ios5, background-image

I'm customizing the `UIButton` programmatically here:

```
button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        [button setSelected:YES];
        button.frame = CGRectMake(x, y, width, height);
        [button setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [button setTitleColor:[UIColor blueColor] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
        [button setTitle:@"Button Title" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"button.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"buttonActive.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
        [button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"buttonActive.png"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
        [button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"buttonActive.png"] forState:UIControlStateDisabled];
```

The issue is if I'm holding down the image background image disappears until I'm releasing it...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you're in overkill mode :). Try setting button.png for UIControlStateNormal and buttonActive.png for UIControlStateHighlighted. No need for the rest. See if this works.

EDIT:

Also, remember: **Image file names are case sensitive**

Are you testing on device? Image names are case sensitive for device builds, but not for the simulator. For example, if your actual image file is named buttonactive.png, but you're calling it as buttonActive.png from your code, it will show up on the simulator, but not on the device.

Please ensure that the case for both image names matches the name of the actual file.

EDIT #2:

Try this code

```
button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [button setSelected:YES];
    button.frame = CGRectMake(x, y, width, height);
    [button setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button setTitleColor:[UIColor blueColor] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
    [button setTitle:@"Button Title" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"button.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"buttonActive.png"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
```

Comment: I might add that image file names are case sensitive on a Device, but NOT in the Simulator. This had me scratching my head a few times :)

Comment: @Sid: I know that the **image names are case sensitive**. I'm testing on the iPhone simulator but should react the same...

Comment: @El.Severo: Did you try setting the image for just those two states?

Comment: @Sid: Yes, but I don't want in that way... I need the title above the button; so the only options will be to place the image in background

Comment: Maybe I should have elaborated... what I meant was leave all of the code the same, except for the last part where you set the images. I have edited my answer so check it out...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4714/discussion-between-el-severo-and-sid)

Answer (score 3):

Figure it out, it works in this way:

```
[_whateverButtonTab setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"ActivateButton.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
[_whateverButtonTab setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"ActivateButton.png"] forState:(UIControlStateHighlighted|UIControlStateSelected)];
```

Answer (score 0):

While we add a button from IDE

sample:

```
.h file
-(IBAction)BtnAdd:(id)sender
```

in `.m` file it is

```
-(IBAction)BtnAdd:(id)sender
{
}
```

It is a method that cannot enable or disable.

so if you want to enable or disable button make it as `-(IBOutlet)BtnAdd`
add `IBOutlet` to `.h` file And connect it to the particular button
then `BtnAdd.enabled=NO` will work