# Can't get object while using UIImage imageNamed:@"cardback"

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage

I'm a beginner at Objective C.
 
I'm trying to add a button to the storyboard. When clicked, the button's background will be changed to another image. However, I'm try to get the background image using :

```
[sender setBackgroundImage: [UIImage imageNamed:@"cardback.jpg"] forState:UIControlStateApplication];
```

It seems that `[UIImage imageNamed:@"cardback.jpg"]` just doesn't get the image object for me.

[image: images]
[codes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wEvI0.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the right UIControlState for the UIButton being pressed?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7999826/whats-the-right-uicontrolstate-for-the-uibutton-being-pressed)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using wrong control state flag. You need to use `UIControlStateNormal` instead of `UIControlStateApplication` for getting the desired result. Refer [UIControlState](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIControl_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/Control_State) for more info. Also you don't need to specify the image extension (because you are loading the image from asset catalog), so remove `.jpg` from the code.

Change:

```
[sender setBackgroundImage: [UIImage imageNamed:@"cardback.jpg"] forState:UIControlStateApplication];
```

to

```
[sender setBackgroundImage: [UIImage imageNamed:@"cardback"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```